# Can't make so that google forms selection box is clicked depending on the text value of the column

Tags: python, pandas, selenium-webdriver

I'm using pandas and Selenium to pass information from an Excel Sheet to a Google form. What I am looking for is the code to click on the Google forms selection box if the text on the column "TF" is "YES".
If it's "NO", simply ignore the selection box.

```
elemento_tf = chrome.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='i35']")
time.sleep(0.5)
df2.loc[df2["TF"]== "YES"] = elemento_tf.click()
```

This is my current code. It always clicks on the selection box even if the text value is "NO".

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your code

1. `.click()` returns `void` (nothing) so assigning a variable to a click action does nothing,

   ```
   df2.loc[df2["TF"]== "YES"] = elemento_tf.click()
   ```
2. I don't understand what this line is supposed to accomplish. You have a `df2.loc[]` index as `True` or `False`...?

   ```
   df2.loc[df2["TF"]== "YES"] = ...
   ```

   which evaluates to

   ```
   df2.loc[True] = ...
   df2.loc[False] = ...
   ```
3. Using `time.sleep()` is a bad practice, use `WebDriverWait` instead.
4. If you are searching for an element by ID, then just use `By.ID()`.

   ```
   (By.XPATH,"//*[@id='i35']")
   ```

   becomes

   ```
   (By.ID,"i35")
   ```

What you are missing is a conditional to check if `df2["TF"]== "YES"` and then code branches based on the evaluation of the condition. Given this, and the suggestions above, I would rewrite the code like

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

if df2["TF"] == "YES":
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"i35"))).click()
```